# WCF 4.0 REST Upload MS-Excel File

Tags: wcf, rest, file-upload

I am trying to upload MS-Excel file through WCF-REST Service.
I used the solution given in below post:-
[RESTful WCF service image upload problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/664712/restful-wcf-service-image-upload-problem)
My POST Method is declared as:

```
  [OperationContract]
                [WebInvoke(Method = "POST", UriTemplate = "/RFQ")]
                [WebContentType("application/octet-stream")]
                void UploadRFQDoc(Stream fileContents);
```

When I debug, stream content is fine till the call goes, and when I attach service to debug,  Stream fileContents  parameter becomes null , and service returns with [Bad Request]. I am not sending large file (it is just 50 KB). I am using HttpClient to call the Post. 
Here are the client code(RestClient is HttpClient).

```
 protected void Post(string uri, Stream stream, int length)
        {
            var content = HttpContent.Create(output => CopyToStream(stream, output, length), "application/octet-stream", length);
            Uri relativeUri = new Uri(uri, UriKind.Relative);

            var resp = RestClient.Post(relativeUri, content);

            ProcessResponse(resp);
        }

        void CopyToStream(Stream input, Stream output, int length)
        {
            var buffer = new byte[length];
            var read = input.Read(buffer, 0, Convert.ToInt32 (length));

            output.Write(buffer, 0, read);
        }
```

Any clue what else can go wrong.
Many Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[WebContentType("application/octet-stream")] attribute was unnecessary here. I commented it out, and all worked fine :).