# What DataType should be used to hold a binary file (eg. Excel file) in 1 parameter of a particular WCF contract?

Tags: c#, wcf, wcf-binding, binaryfiles

I want to write a WCF contract that transports a whole binary file object (eg. Excel file) from the client to the server. What DataType *should* I use for the contract parameter that will hold this binary object?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Jeopardy terms:

What is byte[]?

Comment: Thanks, but what about an IOStream? I think the Client captures the file into an IOStream object, is that not an option, or is it easy to convert one to the other? Here's a link to the **real** issue/question  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10248309/how-to-pass-an-excel-file-from-a-winforms-client-to-a-wcf-service-and-into-an-sq

Comment: Yes, I believe you can use Stream.  http://blogs.msdn.com/b/james_osbornes_blog/archive/2011/06/10/streaming-with-wcf-part-1-custom-stream-implementation.aspx

Comment: For the benefit of others, this one is a little more appropriate ... http://www.digitalcoding.com/Code-Snippets/C-Sharp/C-Code-Snippet-Convert-file-to-byte-array.html

Comment: @Sam - why not use: var data = File.ReadAllBytes(fileName);

Comment: Thanks Chris, I'll try that. I really appreciate your attitude. :-) Have a good one.